# Electronic Convergence issues for DFT+U+SOC in VASP for magnetic materials

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, magnetism

While performing DFT+U+SOC calculation in VASP for the material $\mathrm{Mn_3Sb}$ my calculation is not at all converging. Here I am attaching the necessary input files. I have come across some solutions as described here [link](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/LNONCOLLINEAR) and [link1](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Troubleshooting_electronic_convergence), but could not figure out how to converge this magnetic calculation for DFT+U+SOC.

So here is my `POSCAR` file for $\mathrm{Mn_3Sb}:$

```
Mn3 Sb1
1.0
        3.8133819103         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         3.8133819103         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000         7.6267638206
   Mn   Sb
    6    2
Direct
     0.000000000         0.500000000         0.250000000  
     0.000000000         0.500000000         0.750000000
     0.500000000         0.500000000         0.000000000
     0.500000000         0.500000000         0.500000000
     0.500000000         0.000000000         0.250000000
     0.500000000         0.000000000         0.750000000
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.000000000
     0.000000000         0.000000000         0.500000000
```

And my `INCAR` for the AFM configuration is as follows

```
ISTART    =  0 
ICHARG    =  2               #Non-self-consistent: GGA/LDA band structures)
EDIFF     = 1E-6
ENCUT     = 380              #Cut-off energy for plane wave basis set, in eV
#ISIF     = 3                #optimize atomic coordinates and lattice parameters
#IVDW     = 11               #DFT-D3 method of Grimme with zero damping function
#GGA      = PE               # Perdew-Burke-Ernzerhof (PBE)
ADDGRID   = .TRUE.           #Increase grid; helps GGA convergence

## DOS ##Slaters pauling 18 electrons rule##

ISMEAR    = 0
SIGMA     = 0.02

IBRION    = -1              #Ionic relaxation Algorithm: 0-MD; 1-Quasi-New; 2-CG
ISPIN     = 2
LASPH     = True
LCHARG    = .TRUE.          #Write CHGCAR or not
LNONCOLLINEAR = .TRUE.
LSORBIT   =.True.
LORBMOM   = .TRUE. 
### DFT+U PARAMETER ###

LDAU      = .TRUE.          #switches on DFT+U  
LDAUJ     = 0 0             # J values (For LDAUTYPE=2 , Ueff = U-J)
LDAUL     = 2 -1            #l-quantum number (-1 : no U, 
LDAUPRINT = 1               # 0:silent, 1: write occupancy matrix to OUTCA, 
LDAUTYPE  = 2               #The simplified approach to the DFT+U , introduced by  Dudarev et al.
LDAUU     = 2.0 0           # for Mn:4.0 , Sb:0 ( U values in eV) 
LMAXMIX   = 4               # 4 for d-electrons, 6 for f-electrons
LASPH     = .TRUE.          # non-spherical contributions from the gradient correction inside the PAW spheres will be included as well

###Magnetization###

LORBIT    = 11
SAXIS     = 0 0 4
MAGMOM    = 0 0 -4  0 0 4  0 0 -4  0 0 4  0 0 4  0 0 -4  0 0 0  0 0 0


##Mixer##
  AMIX      = 0.12
  BMIX      = 0.0001
  AMIX_MAG  = 0.82
  BMIX_MAG  = 0.0001


#EDIFFG   = 1E-04      (Ionic convergence; eV/AA)
LREAL     = .FALSE.
LWAVE     = .TRUE.    (determines whether the wavefunctions are written to the WAVECAR file at the end of a run or not)
NELM      = 80
NSW       = 0             # NSW sets the maximum number of ionic steps 
PREC      = High
```

My `KPOINTS` is as follows

```
K-Spacing Value to Generate K-Mesh: 0.030
0
Monkhorst-Pack
   9   9   4
0.0  0.0  0.0
```

And my output showing it's not converging.

```
 running    4 mpi-ranks, on    1 nodes
 distrk:  each k-point on    4 cores,    1 groups
 distr:  one band on    1 cores,    4 groups
 vasp.6.4.2 20Jul23 (build Dec 25 2023 14:50:44) complex                        
  
 POSCAR found type information on POSCAR MnSb
 POSCAR found :  2 types and       8 ions
 scaLAPACK will be used
 LDA part: xc-table for Pade appr. of Perdew
 POSCAR, INCAR and KPOINTS ok, starting setup
 FFT: planning ... GRIDC
 FFT: planning ... GRID_SOFT
 FFT: planning ... GRID
 WAVECAR not read
 entering main loop
       N       E                     dE             d eps       ncg     rms          rms(c)
DAV:   1     0.449739943799E+03    0.44974E+03   -0.15527E+04  6400   0.140E+03
DAV:   2     0.622280929197E+01   -0.44352E+03   -0.43408E+03  6400   0.456E+02
DAV:   3    -0.482008200745E+02   -0.54424E+02   -0.50556E+02  9704   0.195E+02
DAV:   4    -0.557526095931E+02   -0.75518E+01   -0.71185E+01 10432   0.709E+01
DAV:   5    -0.563695094102E+02   -0.61690E+00   -0.60331E+00 10328   0.199E+01    0.161E+01
DAV:   6    -0.533410140836E+02    0.30285E+01   -0.74053E+00 11312   0.336E+01    0.982E+00
DAV:   7    -0.519563261615E+02    0.13847E+01   -0.12416E+01 11488   0.470E+01    0.273E+00
DAV:   8    -0.519103977858E+02    0.45928E-01   -0.10386E+00  9360   0.103E+01    0.183E+00
DAV:   9    -0.518362151764E+02    0.74183E-01   -0.60847E-01  8248   0.544E+00    0.122E+00
DAV:  10    -0.518069760789E+02    0.29239E-01   -0.55223E-01  7288   0.491E+00    0.811E-01
DAV:  11    -0.517958284386E+02    0.11148E-01   -0.37173E-01  7216   0.421E+00    0.528E-01
DAV:  12    -0.517917164650E+02    0.41120E-02   -0.27984E-01  7216   0.356E+00    0.414E-01
DAV:  13    -0.517830417071E+02    0.86748E-02   -0.16471E-01  7216   0.287E+00    0.251E-01
DAV:  14    -0.517824730076E+02    0.56870E-03   -0.13058E-01  7176   0.242E+00    0.209E-01
DAV:  15    -0.517816855964E+02    0.78741E-03   -0.11141E-01  7168   0.218E+00    0.129E-01
DAV:  16    -0.517814850446E+02    0.20055E-03   -0.64790E-02  7168   0.174E+00    0.954E-02
DAV:  17    -0.517819416319E+02   -0.45659E-03   -0.31878E-02  7176   0.123E+00    0.585E-02
DAV:  18    -0.517824481709E+02   -0.50654E-03   -0.17252E-02  7176   0.928E-01    0.476E-02
DAV:  19    -0.517823717352E+02    0.76436E-04   -0.10660E-02  7128   0.729E-01    0.419E-02
DAV:  20    -0.517823138137E+02    0.57921E-04   -0.11218E-02  7064   0.718E-01    0.423E-02
DAV:  21    -0.517823581586E+02   -0.44345E-04   -0.97618E-03  7056   0.669E-01    0.444E-02
DAV:  22    -0.517824474139E+02   -0.89255E-04   -0.12466E-02  7024   0.755E-01    0.319E-02
DAV:  23    -0.517826795974E+02   -0.23218E-03   -0.63997E-03  7008   0.558E-01    0.293E-02
DAV:  24    -0.517827033041E+02   -0.23707E-04   -0.82325E-03  6960   0.613E-01    0.258E-02
DAV:  25    -0.517826323646E+02    0.70940E-04   -0.51839E-03  6952   0.509E-01    0.192E-02
DAV:  26    -0.517826668641E+02   -0.34499E-04   -0.34800E-03  6976   0.438E-01    0.159E-02
DAV:  27    -0.517826745055E+02   -0.76415E-05   -0.19043E-03  7032   0.339E-01    0.127E-02
DAV:  28    -0.517826597822E+02    0.14723E-04   -0.24527E-03  6864   0.409E-01    0.954E-03
DAV:  29    -0.517827008211E+02   -0.41039E-04   -0.13403E-03  6880   0.286E-01    0.136E-02
DAV:  30    -0.517827306854E+02   -0.29864E-04   -0.31719E-03  6832   0.411E-01    0.156E-02
DAV:  31    -0.517826799760E+02    0.50709E-04   -0.20284E-03  6824   0.353E-01    0.108E-02
DAV:  32    -0.517826956097E+02   -0.15634E-04   -0.17900E-03  6816   0.357E-01    0.127E-02
DAV:  33    -0.517826942232E+02    0.13866E-05   -0.27314E-03  6736   0.368E-01    0.160E-02
DAV:  34    -0.517827565430E+02   -0.62320E-04   -0.37554E-03  6704   0.424E-01    0.184E-02
DAV:  35    -0.517827289587E+02    0.27584E-04   -0.35617E-03  6688   0.424E-01    0.146E-02
DAV:  36    -0.517826879392E+02    0.41019E-04   -0.15754E-03  6688   0.335E-01    0.883E-03
DAV:  37    -0.517826758255E+02    0.12114E-04   -0.14120E-03  6688   0.323E-01    0.711E-03
DAV:  38    -0.517827088385E+02   -0.33013E-04   -0.15911E-03  6672   0.319E-01    0.123E-02
DAV:  39    -0.517826538351E+02    0.55003E-04   -0.80932E-04  6688   0.247E-01    0.466E-03
DAV:  40    -0.517826696179E+02   -0.15783E-04   -0.85738E-04  6696   0.279E-01    0.696E-03
DAV:  41    -0.517827197438E+02   -0.50126E-04   -0.99378E-04  6664   0.233E-01    0.137E-02
DAV:  42    -0.517827356752E+02   -0.15931E-04   -0.32448E-03  6592   0.408E-01    0.151E-02
DAV:  43    -0.517827416500E+02   -0.59748E-05   -0.12912E-03  6592   0.277E-01    0.152E-02
DAV:  44    -0.517826831414E+02    0.58509E-04   -0.25744E-03  6544   0.375E-01    0.984E-03
DAV:  45    -0.517826773047E+02    0.58367E-05   -0.59249E-04  6768   0.225E-01    0.935E-03
DAV:  46    -0.517826589605E+02    0.18344E-04   -0.10712E-03  6576   0.265E-01    0.586E-03
DAV:  47    -0.517827277722E+02   -0.68812E-04   -0.13122E-03  6528   0.273E-01    0.138E-02
DAV:  48    -0.517827114814E+02    0.16291E-04   -0.32180E-03  6512   0.407E-01    0.138E-02
DAV:  49    -0.517827141822E+02   -0.27007E-05   -0.12539E-03  6512   0.280E-01    0.109E-02
DAV:  50    -0.517827177136E+02   -0.35314E-05   -0.25305E-03  6496   0.370E-01    0.126E-02
DAV:  51    -0.517827443097E+02   -0.26596E-04   -0.34811E-03  6488   0.417E-01    0.165E-02
DAV:  52    -0.517827103975E+02    0.33912E-04   -0.21587E-03  6488   0.336E-01    0.116E-02
DAV:  53    -0.517827557456E+02   -0.45348E-04   -0.27325E-03  6488   0.369E-01    0.180E-02
DAV:  54    -0.517827846982E+02   -0.28953E-04   -0.49826E-03  6480   0.484E-01    0.191E-02
DAV:  55    -0.517827445492E+02    0.40149E-04   -0.49158E-03  6472   0.496E-01    0.171E-02
DAV:  56    -0.517827693124E+02   -0.24763E-04   -0.45599E-03  6456   0.472E-01    0.182E-02
DAV:  57    -0.517826904181E+02    0.78894E-04   -0.29253E-03  6464   0.393E-01    0.117E-02
DAV:  58    -0.517826843632E+02    0.60549E-05   -0.13158E-03  6480   0.285E-01    0.830E-03
DAV:  59    -0.517826932285E+02   -0.88653E-05   -0.18202E-03  6472   0.355E-01    0.832E-03
DAV:  60    -0.517826856487E+02    0.75798E-05   -0.12909E-03  6448   0.298E-01    0.816E-03
DAV:  61    -0.517827261128E+02   -0.40464E-04   -0.17119E-03  6448   0.313E-01    0.146E-02
DAV:  62    -0.517826902732E+02    0.35840E-04   -0.23715E-03  6440   0.352E-01    0.102E-02
DAV:  63    -0.517827242603E+02   -0.33987E-04   -0.21106E-03  6432   0.342E-01    0.142E-02
DAV:  64    -0.517827260940E+02   -0.18336E-05   -0.86564E-04  6448   0.237E-01    0.136E-02
DAV:  65    -0.517826862622E+02    0.39832E-04   -0.92091E-04  6464   0.229E-01    0.112E-02
DAV:  66    -0.517827140223E+02   -0.27760E-04   -0.15499E-03  6440   0.284E-01    0.132E-02
DAV:  67    -0.517826918872E+02    0.22135E-04   -0.10583E-03  6448   0.251E-01    0.116E-02
DAV:  68    -0.517827013410E+02   -0.94538E-05   -0.12825E-03  6432   0.270E-01    0.105E-02
DAV:  69    -0.517827036806E+02   -0.23396E-05   -0.12956E-03  6432   0.284E-01    0.120E-02
DAV:  70    -0.517826937204E+02    0.99602E-05   -0.18128E-03  6432   0.341E-01    0.101E-02
DAV:  71    -0.517827143013E+02   -0.20581E-04   -0.20299E-03  6432   0.342E-01    0.139E-02
DAV:  72    -0.517826850340E+02    0.29267E-04   -0.21616E-03  6432   0.354E-01    0.938E-03
DAV:  73    -0.517826932889E+02   -0.82548E-05   -0.19624E-03  6432   0.356E-01    0.112E-02
DAV:  74    -0.517826702590E+02    0.23030E-04   -0.12319E-03  6432   0.270E-01    0.818E-03
DAV:  75    -0.517827154231E+02   -0.45164E-04   -0.77737E-04  6432   0.229E-01    0.122E-02
DAV:  76    -0.517827440021E+02   -0.28579E-04   -0.87226E-04  6416   0.210E-01    0.162E-02
DAV:  77    -0.517826825655E+02    0.61437E-04   -0.54417E-04  6416   0.188E-01    0.969E-03
DAV:  78    -0.517827138369E+02   -0.31271E-04   -0.12501E-04  6608   0.916E-02    0.133E-02
DAV:  79    -0.517827152184E+02   -0.13815E-05   -0.86426E-05  6688   0.760E-02    0.136E-02
DAV:  80    -0.517827135672E+02    0.16512E-05   -0.43654E-05  6768   0.546E-02    0.129E-02
DAV:  81    -0.517827214476E+02   -0.78804E-05   -0.18929E-04  6440   0.106E-01    0.144E-02
DAV:  82    -0.517827369411E+02   -0.15494E-04   -0.28739E-04  6416   0.123E-01    0.159E-02
DAV:  83    -0.517827357905E+02    0.11507E-05   -0.18930E-05  7528   0.390E-02    0.158E-02
DAV:  84    -0.517827360473E+02   -0.25683E-06   -0.29035E-05  6608   0.407E-02    0.156E-02
DAV:  85    -0.517827412186E+02   -0.51713E-05   -0.50712E-05  6448   0.561E-02    0.164E-02
DAV:  86    -0.517827587225E+02   -0.17504E-04   -0.17786E-04  6416   0.103E-01    0.181E-02
DAV:  87    -0.517827565276E+02    0.21950E-05   -0.18571E-05  7328   0.357E-02    0.180E-02
DAV:  88    -0.517827550209E+02    0.15066E-05   -0.13599E-05  6560   0.275E-02    0.178E-02
DAV:  89    -0.517827337255E+02    0.21295E-04   -0.88592E-05  6416   0.748E-02    0.161E-02
DAV:  90    -0.517827477376E+02   -0.14012E-04   -0.61363E-05  6432   0.597E-02    0.171E-02
DAV:  91    -0.517827318118E+02    0.15926E-04   -0.15418E-04  6416   0.103E-01    0.157E-02
DAV:  92    -0.517827072168E+02    0.24595E-04   -0.15934E-04  6416   0.935E-02    0.134E-02
DAV:  93    -0.517826992531E+02    0.79637E-05   -0.40247E-04  6416   0.152E-01    0.123E-02
DAV:  94    -0.517826993007E+02   -0.47651E-07   -0.17723E-04  6416   0.103E-01    0.132E-02
DAV:  95    -0.517827263911E+02   -0.27090E-04   -0.95310E-05  6416   0.824E-02    0.153E-02
DAV:  96    -0.517827046348E+02    0.21756E-04   -0.22103E-04  6416   0.117E-01    0.123E-02
DAV:  97    -0.517827025120E+02    0.21228E-05   -0.96605E-05  6432   0.847E-02    0.130E-02
DAV:  98    -0.517827354612E+02   -0.32949E-04   -0.16619E-04  6416   0.990E-02    0.163E-02
DAV:  99    -0.517827166861E+02    0.18775E-04   -0.20274E-04  6416   0.110E-01    0.139E-02
DAV: 100    -0.517827165430E+02    0.14305E-06   -0.13743E-05  7288   0.354E-02
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                             |
|           W    W    AA    RRRRR   N    N  II  N    N   GGGG   !!!           |
|           W    W   A  A   R    R  NN   N  II  NN   N  G    G  !!!           |
|           W    W  A    A  R    R  N N  N  II  N N  N  G       !!!           |
|           W WW W  AAAAAA  RRRRR   N  N N  II  N  N N  G  GGG   !            |
|           WW  WW  A    A  R   R   N   NN  II  N   NN  G    G                |
|           W    W  A    A  R    R  N    N  II  N    N   GGGG   !!!           |
|                                                                             |
|     The electronic self-consistency was not achieved in the given           |
|     number of steps (NELM). The forces and other quantities evaluated       |
|     might not be reliable so examine the results carefully. If you find     |
|     spurious results, we suggest increasing NELM, if you were close to      |
|     convergence or switching to a different ALGO or adjusting the           |
|     density mixing parameters otherwise.                                    |
|                                                                             |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 F= -.51782717E+02 E0= -.51782042E+02  d E =-.134961E-02  mag=     0.0000     0.0000    -0.0000
 writing wavefunctions
```

Any suggestions and solutions are appreciated.
First `Edit1`: NELM=100 and its output

Comment: Maybe you can increase the NELM a little bit more maybe 100 or above and observe whether the system is moving towards convergence or not. If you could provide the full log that would be better.

Comment: Sure i am trying for the NELM=100 and updating the full log.

Comment: Are you performin DFT+U and SoC in one run?

Comment: Yes DFT+U+SOC in one run.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to do DFT+U first, save the WAVECAR file and use it for the next run with SoC (for SoC one needs to use vasp_ncl not vasp_std). For SoC, I usually use ISYM = -1, ISMEAR = -5. In one example from VASP wiki https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Including_the_Spin-Orbit_Coupling You can see that they used tetrahedron method (ISMEAR = -5)

Comment: @JaafarMehrez Not converging.  I have used `ISMEAR = 0` and `ISYM=-1`.

Comment: sorry for not following up. Yeah i faced the same issue. Is there any  solution to this issue?